# office365 graph api to assign owner rights on private groups

Tags: office365, azure-ad-graph-api, office365api

I want to find mechanism to add specific users as owner of private groups.

I tried MS Graph API, but it looks like there is rest api to assign owner rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add group owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) allows you to add a user to the O365 group's owners.

See this sample:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/owners/$ref
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"
}
```

Comment: how to get list of just private groups

Comment: Query filter for property 'visibility' of resource 'Group' is not supported currently. You can list all groups and handle 'visibility' property in your code.